# Mac OS event message window?

Tags: mac

I am new to Mac, and somehow some event details window is enabled in my Mac mini, it's irritating and I don't want it.

I don't know what we call this window, see the attached image for details. Please check and guide me how to disable this window.

In the pic below its the window which is showing "You are currently on a text....".

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the "caption panel" from VoiceOver, an accessibility technology primarily targeted at the vision-impaired. To disable VoiceOver, hit Cmd-F5 (you'd have to also hold down the "Fn" key if you were on a MacBook). To learn more about VoiceOver, go to the "Universal Access" panel in System Preferences.

Comment: Yes, yesterday I used "Cmd + f5" when I was using Safari, I thought it will refresh the page, but nothing happens and I think due to which this was enabled. Thanks @spiff its disabled now :)

Comment: Glad I could help. By the way, Cmd-R is Reload Page in Safari (and is often used as reload/refresh in other Mac apps as well).

Comment: @Prashant You can disable accessibility keyboard shortcuts in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Universal Access* if you don't use them.